# create a temporary sql table using recursion as a loop to populate custom time interval

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion

Suppose you have a table like:

```
id  subscription_start  subscription_end    segment
1   2016-12-01  2017-02-01  87
2   2016-12-01  2017-01-24  87
...
```

And wish to generate a temporary table with months.

One way would be to encode the month date as:

```
with months as (
   select
     '2016-12-01' as 'first',
     '2016-12-31' as 'last'
   union
   select 
     '2017-01-01' as 'first',
     '2017-01-31' as 'last'
   ...
) select  * from months;
```

So that I have an output table like:

```
first_day   last_day
2017-01-01  2017-01-31
2017-02-01  2017-02-31
2017-03-01  2017-03-31
```

I would like to generate a temporary table with a custom interval (above), without manually encoding all the dates.

Say the interval is of 12 months, for each year, for as many years there are in the db.
I'd like to have general approach to compute the `months` table with the same output as above.

Or, one may adjust the range to a custom interval (months split an year in 12 parts, but one may want to split a time in a custom interval of days).

To start, I was thinking to use recursive query like:

```
  with months(id, first_day, last_day, month) as (
  select
    id,
    first_day,
    last_day,
    0
  where
    subscriptions.first_day = min(subscriptions.first_day)
  union all
  select
    id,
    first_day,
    last_day,
    months.month + 1
  from
    subscriptions
    left join months on cast(
      strftime('%m', datetime(subscriptions.subscription_start)) as int
    ) = months.month
  where
    months.month < 13
)
select
  *
from
  months
where
  month = 1;
```

but it does not do what I'd expect: here I was attempting to select the first row from the table with the minimum date, and populate a table at interval of months, ranging from 1 to 12. For each month, I was comparing the string date field of my table (e.g. 2017-03-01  = 3 is march).

The query above does work and also seems a bit complicated, but for the sake of learning, which alternative would you propose to create a temporary table `months` without manually coding the intervals ?

Comment: I am a bit unclear on (1) What is the result that you are looking for (please show it as tabular text)? (2) Does you current query generate the desired results or not?

Comment: thank you @GMB, added an ouput table (1) and current query does not generate desidered result (2). Looking for a query that provide desired results without manually encoding the dates, and where one could specify a custom time range. I was trying to use recursion for there is no loop on sql.